# How to create htaccess with redirect html and get parameter from last of url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url :

**http://localhost/panel/dev/dashboard**

how to create htaccess, i want to :

**http://localhost/panel/home.php?i=dashboard**

Comment: you have this url :`http://localhost/panel/home.php?i=dashboard` and you want it to be : `http://localhost/panel/dev/dashboard` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RedirectRule ^/panel/dev/(.+)$ /panel/home.php?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```